# How to implement Microdata for organization's product or service

Tags: schema.org, microdata

If my company do it product (website, design, app), what should I apply Microdata to my HTML, if HTML structure look like below:

```html
<div>
<h1>Company name</h1>
<p>Below is our portfolio</p>
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/???">
<h2>1. Website name</h2>
   <p>Website info here...</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Do you want to know which Schema.org type you should use for portfolio entries?

Comment: If my product is website should I use itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" or itemtype="http://schema.org/WebApplication" or itemtype="http://schema.org/Service"

Comment: Then, could you [edit] your question? Currently you have `Organization` -- do you want to keep it? And where exactly do you expect to use `Product`/`Service`/`WebApplication`?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what this content is exactly about.

If it’s something your [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization) offers (so the portfolio item is a placeholder for what your business offers), you could use:

[`makesOffer`](http://schema.org/makesOffer) → [`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer)

If it’s something your [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization) owns (so the portfolio item is something your business wants to show), you could use:

[`owns`](http://schema.org/owns) → [`Product`](http://schema.org/Product)

From the perspective of the [`CreativeWork`](http://schema.org/CreativeWork), you could link to your [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization) using the properties [`author`](http://schema.org/author)/[`creator`](http://schema.org/creator), [`contributor`](http://schema.org/contributor), [`copyrightHolder`](http://schema.org/copyrightHolder), [`provider`](http://schema.org/provider), or [`publisher`](http://schema.org/publisher).

Answer (score 0):

1- You can use, Like Unor said, the Organization, but there is some specific types of organizations. 
You can use LocalBusiness and in your case, I will use another specific type of LocalBusiness wich calls https://schema.org/ProfessionalService. (provider)

An exemple of use :

```
<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ProfessionalService" style="display:none;">
        <span itemprop="name">company name</span>
        <span itemprop="description" style="display:none;">Description </span>
        <img itemprop="logo" src="http://logo-url" alt="">
        <span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
            <span itemprop="streetAddress">Address</span>, 
            <span itemprop="addressLocality">Locality</span> 
            <span itemprop="addressCountry" >Canada</span>
            <span itemprop="addressRegion">State_or_province</span>
            <span itemprop="postalCode">Postal_code</span>
        </span>
        <span itemprop="geo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates">
            <meta itemprop="latitude" content="45.5354467" />
            <meta itemprop="longitude" content="-73.505216" />
        </span>
</span>
```

I advise you to use the GeoCoordinates, because Google should promote your web site in your local area.
You can hide this information for users by an style="display:none".

2- For your portfolio, you have another schema : CreativeWork

3- For the use of offer : you have to indicate the price that could be show directly in search results. But in your case, I don't think you want it :).

Microdata can change the appearance of your page directly in search results. For more information, [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/)